# OpenVPN activation of network connection failed v

Tags: 18.04, openvpn

I'm trying to set a vpn on Ubuntu 18 in ethernet via network manager
Whenever i connect with valid credentials it keeps asking for password and then prompts `activation of network connection failed`

i tried re-installing the necessary packages but nothing works.

The VPN is openvpn

also tried Via cli 
:error

```
sudo openvpn pl.ovpn
Wed Dec 18 06:23:53 2019 OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2019
Wed Dec 18 06:23:53 2019 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08
Enter Auth Username: megsbarliso
Enter Auth Password: *****************

Wed Dec 18 06:23:59 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]
Wed Dec 18 06:23:59 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Wed Dec 18 06:23:59 2019 UDP link local: (not bound)
Wed Dec 18 06:23:59 2019 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]
Wed Dec 18 06:23:59 2019 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET], sid=45a01c11 79e0c228
Wed Dec 18 06:23:59 2019 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Wed Dec 18 06:23:59 2019 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=ovpn1.va.pl.net
Wed Dec 18 06:23:59 2019 VERIFY KU OK
Wed Dec 18 06:23:59 2019 Validating certificate extended key usage
Wed Dec 18 06:23:59 2019 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Wed Dec 18 06:23:59 2019 VERIFY EKU OK
Wed Dec 18 06:23:59 2019 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server
Wed Dec 18 06:24:02 2019 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Wed Dec 18 06:24:02 2019 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]54.83.118.102:1194
Wed Dec 18 06:24:03 2019 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Wed Dec 18 06:24:03 2019 AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED
Wed Dec 18 06:24:03 2019 SIGTERM[soft,auth-failure] received, process exiting
vcg@vcg-MS-7C13:~$
```

as suggested the following command `dpkg -l *network-manager* | grep ii` outputs the following

```
ii  network-manager                            1.10.6-2ubuntu1.2           amd64        network management framework (daemon and userspace tools)
ii  network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.2           all          NetworkManager configuration to enable connectivity checking
ii  network-manager-gnome                      1.8.10-2ubuntu3             amd64        network management framework (GNOME frontend)
ii  network-manager-l2tp                       1.2.16-1~ubuntu18.04.1~ppa1 amd64        network management framework (L2TP plugin core)
ii  network-manager-l2tp-gnome                 1.2.16-1~ubuntu18.04.1~ppa1 amd64        network management framework (L2TP plugin GNOME GUI)
ii  network-manager-openvpn                    1.8.2-1                     amd64        network management framework (OpenVPN plugin core)
ii  network-manager-openvpn-gnome              1.8.2-1                     amd64        network management framework (OpenVPN plugin GNOME GUI)
ii  network-manager-pptp                       1.2.6-1                     amd64        network management framework (PPTP plugin core)
ii  network-manager-pptp-gnome                 1.2.6-1                     amd64        network management framework (PPTP plugin GNOME GUI)
```

i tried a public ovpn file that doesn't have auth required and this is the output

```
sudo openvpn USA_135.180.79.35_tcp.ovpn
Thu Dec 19 01:28:44 2019 OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2019
Thu Dec 19 01:28:44 2019 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08
Thu Dec 19 01:28:44 2019 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Thu Dec 19 01:28:44 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]135.180.79.35:1557
Thu Dec 19 01:28:44 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->131072] S=[16384->16384]
Thu Dec 19 01:28:44 2019 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]135.180.79.35:1557 [nonblock]
Thu Dec 19 01:28:45 2019 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]135.180.79.35:1557
Thu Dec 19 01:28:45 2019 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Thu Dec 19 01:28:45 2019 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]135.180.79.35:1557
Thu Dec 19 01:28:45 2019 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]135.180.79.35:1557, sid=8ad9b726 45231acc
Thu Dec 19 01:28:46 2019 VERIFY OK: depth=2, C=GB, ST=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
Thu Dec 19 01:28:46 2019 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=GB, ST=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
Thu Dec 19 01:28:46 2019 VERIFY OK: depth=0, OU=Domain Control Validated, OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN=*.opengw.net
Thu Dec 19 01:28:46 2019 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Thu Dec 19 01:28:46 2019 [*.opengw.net] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]135.180.79.35:1557
Thu Dec 19 01:28:47 2019 SENT CONTROL [*.opengw.net]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Thu Dec 19 01:28:48 2019 AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED
Thu Dec 19 01:28:48 2019 SIGTERM[soft,auth-failure] received, process exiting
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102352/discussion-on-question-by-megs-barliso-openvpn-activation-of-network-connection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public OpenVPN .ovpn files can be downloaded from https://www.freeopenvpn.org/en/cf/usa.php

Some work, some don't. Auth failures.

Contact the VPN provider and tell them they've either got some bad .ovpn files, or one or more bad servers.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message "activation of network connection failed" on enabling a VPN. Turned out earlier I'd unwittingly blown away the .crt and .key files that the VPN was configured to use.